# Moongose not updating Nested Arrary

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

```
  Datemodel = {
    "_id": "5922f58599ff690ea4ffb4cd",
      "events": [
        {
          "eventDate": "2017-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",
          "eventName": "Project Name",
          "_id": "591e953982c0423238721b09"
        },
        {
          "eventDate": "2017-05-15T18:30:00.000Z",
          "eventName": "Project Name",
          "_id": "591e953982c0423238721b08"
        },
        {
          "eventDate": "2017-05-29T18:30:00.000Z",
          "eventName": "Project Name",
          "_id": "591e953982c0423238721b07"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to update the value of eventName whose events._ID is 591e953982c0423238721b09

i have performed the below query

```
    router.route('/postPhase')
      .post(function (req, res) {
 var eventID = req.body.eventID
var eventName = req.body.eventName
var query = {
 events._id: eventID
}
dataModal.findOneAndUpdate(query,{$set:{events.$.eventName:"eventName"}},{"new":true},function(err, Data){
res.json(data)

})

})
```

Please help me to get the data updated into the database

Comment: Try `var query = {
 "events._id": eventID
}`

Comment: `query = { "events._id": eventID }`. Your missing the period `.`

Comment: it was typoerror here only

Comment: Make sure you have a valid input value and has the matching type in mongodb. This could be string vs objectId for ObjectId type. Try casting the string to objectid in the query. `var query = { "events._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(eventID) }`

Comment: still not working